# Is there a way to refactor swift 3.0 code to swift 5.5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-silicon

I've seen in the past that it would be possible by installing Xcode 10.1 and converting the code. However Im on apple silicon and anytime I go to open 10.1 it opens the most recent version of xcode which is 13 and some change.  I was curious if i could even run 10.1  but it seems not. Anybody have a current way to convert a swift 3.0 project to a more current version of swift?

Comment: You could run 10.1 in a virtual machine, eg Parallels. Personally I would just compile the code and fix the errors by hand.

Comment: I cant even build in 13.

Comment: Yes, you might need to migrate the code into a fresh project.